# Should I use my primary Apple ID for that or create another one to use with Apple Developer account?

Tags: apple-id, developer-program

I’m thinking about getting an Apple Developer account. But not sure whether I should tie it to my primary Apple ID that I use on all my devices. Will this has an effect on beta testing, or anything?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/) page:

> ### Enrolling as an Individual
>
> If you are an individual or sole proprietor/single person business, get started by signing in with your Apple ID with two-factor authentication turned on. You’ll need to provide basic personal information, including your legal name and address.

If you use a different Apple ID, you need at least one device with this Apple ID signed-in to authenticate your login, because of mandatory two-factor authentication. Switching your Apple ID on a device is not something you want to do regularily.

Answer (score 0):

The only downside I can see for this is two:

1. If you want to not share your legal name and address with Apple (who will share your legal name but not your address when you publish any app online) you should form an LLC and use that for your development.
2. If you are not willing to enable TFA for your account, you’ll be forced to do that as a paid developer.

I don’t see any real reason to not go ahead with keeping your same AppleID initially. You can always transfer things later if you need to.

So, yes - I think people should use their primary AppleID to start developing.